# Stubbing $.get function using teaspoon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, stub, sinon, teaspoon

I have a javascript function like the one below

```
function_name: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.get('something',{
        target : 'something',
        param1 : 'somevalue',
    })
}
```

I need to stub $.get function using teaspoon. could I get any snippet to solve using teaspoon or sinon stub

#### Updated

I was able to solve this issue using the following code

```
var ajax_get_stub = sinon.stub($, 'get').returns($.Deferred().resolve({}).promise());

expect(ajax_get_stub.withArgs('resource', { param1: 'value' }).calledOnce).to.be(true);

$.get.restore();
```

Comment: How about answering your own question below ;-)